# TikZ Graph with \usebox commands not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, graphs

I would like to connect "components", which I create with `TikZ` and store as a `savebox` to later incorporate into the final drawing. When using the `graph` command, the output is not what I expect. I though the top and bottom images would appear identical (barring the alignment, which your comments are welcome on explaining). Basically, the graph stops drawing after a middle blank node. Additionally, setting `below=of lbus` does not align as expected

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,graphs}

\begin{document}

%%% circuit breaker symbol, I will have other, more complicated \usebox drawings in the final picture
%%% simple example shown for simplicity
\newsavebox{\tikzBRKt}
\savebox{\tikzBRKt}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\tikzBRK}{\usebox{\tikzBRKt}}


\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0pt,]
    \tikzset{node distance = 1cm and 2cm}
\coordinate (bjunc);
\node (rbrk)     [right= of bjunc] {\tikzBRK};
\node (lbrk)     [left= of bjunc] {\tikzBRK};
\node (lbus)    [left=of lbrk] {};
\node (rbus)    [right=of rbrk] {};
\draw (lbrk) edge (bjunc) edge (rbrk)
      (lbus) edge (lbrk)
      (rbus) edge (rbrk);

    \begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm, below=of lbus] % todo also not sure why below lbus doesnt work here?
        \graph [grow right sep=2cm]{ lbus1/ -- "\tikzBRK" -- bjunc1/ -- "\tikzBRK" -- rbus1/ }; % todo why isnt this working
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extended comment. When you say that something is "not working" you benefit a lot from indicating what the expected result is. The saveboxes behave no different from ordinary edge labels: if you place two identical ones in your setup, the second one will be swallowed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,graphs}

\begin{document}

%%% circuit breaker symbol, I will have other, more complicated \usebox drawings in the final picture
%%% simple example shown for simplicity
\newsavebox{\tikzBRKt}
\savebox{\tikzBRKt}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\tikzBRK}{\usebox{\tikzBRKt}}


\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0pt,]
    \tikzset{node distance = 1cm and 2cm}
\coordinate (bjunc);
\node (rbrk)     [right= of bjunc] {\tikzBRK};
\node (lbrk)     [left= of bjunc] {\tikzBRK};
\node (lbus)    [left=of lbrk] {};
\node (rbus)    [right=of rbrk] {};
\draw (lbrk) edge (bjunc) edge (rbrk)
      (lbus) edge (lbrk)
      (rbus) edge (rbrk);


\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm,local bounding box=A1]
  \graph [grow right sep=2cm]{ lbus1/ -- "A" -- bjunc1/ -- "A" -- rbus1/ }; 
\end{scope}
\path (A1.west) node[left]{``not working''};

\begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm,local bounding box=A2]
  \graph [grow right sep=2cm]{ lbus1/ -- "A" -- bjunc1/ -- "B" -- rbus1/ }; 
\end{scope}
\path (A2.west) node[left]{``working''};


\begin{scope}[yshift=-6cm,local bounding box=A3]
  \graph [grow right sep=2cm]{ lbus1/ -- "\tikzBRK" -- bjunc1/ -- "\tikzBRK" -- rbus1/ }; 
\end{scope}
\path (A3.west) node[left]{``not working''};


\begin{scope}[yshift=-8cm,local bounding box=A4]
  \graph [grow right sep=2cm]{ lbus1/ -- "\tikzBRK" -- bjunc1/ -- "{}\tikzBRK" -- rbus1/ }; 
\end{scope}
\path (A4.west) node[left]{``working''};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is because, in your setting, the label also serves as an identifier. So the output of save boxes matches expectations.

By the same token, I do not understand your concerns regarding `below=of lbus` because there is no indication what the expected result is, and how the actual result differs from that.

Comment: Thanks--based on your answer I also found out that another way to achieve my desired result is: `lbus1/ -- /"\tikzBRK" -- bjunc1/ -- /"\tikzBRK" -- rbus1/ }` , using the unnamed nodes. As for the `below= of lbus`,  I expected that the `scope` would begin below where the point `lbus` is defined, but it is offset and begins at the middle node.

Comment: @likethevegetable Oh, nice! As for the `below of` stuff, this gets applied to the nodes seperately as far as I know, so the nodes receive conflicting placement information.

Comment: thanks, I will likely ask another question then and be more specific.