# Position the beginning node of a graph with respect to another node

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, positioning, nodes

I would like to start a `graph`'s first node (G1) with respect to another pre-existing node (N1), using the `positioning` library. I would like it to appear as follows:

```
N1
G1 -  - G2
        N2
```

I've included a MWE below.

My first attempt was to specify `\path[below=of N1]` at the beginning of the graph, but that did not work as the G1 and the following graph were in line.

My second attempt which brings me very close to what I want, is to define a coordinate `[below=of N1](Gstart)`, and `shift` the graph. The slight issue with this is that `G1` is slightly offset (see the red ink I've marked up the picture with).

Note that I can position node N2 wrt the graph node G2 as I expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,graphs}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0pt,]
\tikzset{node distance = 1cm and 2cm}

\node (N1) {N1};

%%% First attempt
\path[below=of N1] graph [grow right sep=2cm]{ G1 -- P/ -- G2};  %%% graph doesnt start below if I try this

%%% My solution, gets me a bit close, but the graph is horizontally offset a bit
\coordinate [below=of N1](Gstart);
\path[shift={(Gstart)}] graph [grow right sep=2cm]{ G1 -- P/ -- G2};  %%% graph doesnt start below

\node (N2) [below=of G2] {N2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please see the answer below if it meets the requirement

Answer (score 0):

Is it still relevant whether instead of setting `G1` below `N1` you declare `N1` above `G1` ?
which yields :

```
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0pt]
\tikzset{node distance = 1cm and 2cm}
%%% First attempt
%\path graph [grow right sep=2cm]{ G1 -- P/ -- G2};  %%% graph doesnt start below if I try this

%%% My solution, gets me a bit close, but the graph is horizontally offset a bit
\path graph[grow right sep=1cm]{G1--P/--G2};  %%% graph doesnt start below
\node(N2)[below=of G2] {N2};
\node[above of =G1](N1){N1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: N1 might be a part of another, more complicated structure, and to satisfy my curiosity and understanding, I would prefer the original problem statement be answered.

Answer (score 0):

I have not gone into the merits of your placement

The problem you face can be resolved with the solution given at page 301 of the `pgf` manual by using graphs with the option `[no placement]`

Graphs can be placed on a grid to your choice by varying the x and y coordinate -- additionally once a coordinate is set it will remain set for the next node in the graph which can be placed only by varying one coordinate `x` or `y` -- there is no need to vary both coords

For a better understanding see the example below

```
\tikz \graph [no placement]
{
    a ->
    { [x=1] % group option
        b [y=0] -> c[y=1]
    };
};
```

which results in

[image]

Applying the same strategy to you case using the code --

```
\tikz\graph[no placement]
{
N1,
G1[y=-1]--G2[x=2,y=-1]
};
```

results in

[image]

As you see there is no alignment problem -- you can now expand on the graph as per your requirement

**Complete MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,graphs}

\begin{document}

\tikz\graph[no placement]
{
N1,
G1[y=-1]--G2[x=2,y=-1]
};
\end{document}
```

**EDIT Second trial**   adapted from --
[TikZ Graph with \usebox commands not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574142/tikz-graph-with-usebox-commands-not-working)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,graphs}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0pt,]
\tikzset{node distance = 1cm and 2cm}
\coordinate (m);
\node (n)     [right= 0pt of m] {N1};


\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm,local bounding box=A1]
      \graph [grow right sep=2cm]{ "G1" -- b/ -- "G2"}; 
    



\end{scope}
\path (A1.west) node[below=1em, align =left]{``working with N1\\ outside the scope''};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I asked the question mainly because let's say N1 is a part of some complex construction that does not require a graph. Your answer provides some useful insight, however does not directly answer the question. Thank you though!

Comment: an elaboration is required --   `N1 is a part of some complex construction that does not require a graph`

Comment: I'm simply suggesting that the solution I'm seeking requires that N1 be defined before and outside the graph, and that the graph be positioned relative to N1.

Comment: @likethevegetable  please see the edited answer above if it meets the requirement -- N1 is now placed outside the graph containing G1 and G2

Comment: It is, but the issue I see is that N1 was defined with respect to another coordinate, m. My question required that a graph be placed with respect to an arbitrary node. If n is positioned somewhere else on the x axis, the graph doesn't move with it.